# Disable TouchId when resuming from suspend BUT leaving it enabled for sudo

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, touch-id

I've recently switched my development setup to a new M2 Mac Book Air with Touch ID support. Right now I'm tailoring my laptop to my liking. I've added Touch Id as a supported PAM authentication method:

```
auth sufficient pam_tid.so
```

which works fine in iterm2 - when elevating privileges in the terminal I'm being prompted for my fingerprint.

Unfortunately I really need to disable fingerprint authentication when resuming my laptop from sleep. After toggling `"System Preferences"->"Use Touch ID for"->"Unlocking your Mac"` both sudo and the unlock screen stop asking me for my fingerprint.

Is there any way to enable fingerprint authentication when using sudo but disabling it for the unlock screen?